# In how many days will both working together complete the 3 times of original work? (a GMAT exam question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Eklavya can do 6 times the actual work in 36 days while Faizal can do one-fourth of the original work in 3 days. In how many days will both working together complete the 3 times of original work?

What is the difference between actual and original work?
I calculated the efficiency of Eklavya by diving $100/6=16.66%$
efficiency of Faizal is given as $8.33%$. How to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a poorly worded question. They are trying to give you the rates at which the two individuals can do the work. Eklavya can work at a rate of $\frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6} \frac{\text{ jobs }}{\text{day}}$ while Faizal works at a rate of $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{3} = \frac{1}{12}\frac{\text{ jobs }}{\text{day}} $.

I think they want to know how much time it would take the two of them working together to complete 3 days worth of work. To solve this, we use the rates they gave us:

$$
\frac{1}{6}w + \frac{1}{12}w = 3
$$

where $w$ is the number of days it will take.

Solving this we get:

$$
w = 12 \text{ days}
$$

I don't think the terms "original" work and "actual" work are supposed to mean anything particular.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the actual work $W_{0}$.

Eklavya can do $\frac{6}{36}W_{0} = \frac{1}{6}W_{0}$ per day.

Faizal can do $\frac{1}{12}W_{0}$ per day

So we have to solve $3W_{0} = \frac{1}{6}W_{0}T + \frac{1}{12}W_{0}T $ with $T$ in days. So it boils down to solving the simple equation $3 = \frac{1}{6}T + \frac{1}{12}T $

Hope this helps